# Host multiple .Net Core websites in a single AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm able to setup a docker-compose script to run multiple .Net Core website containers on my local docker windows. I'm able to access to each of the websites locally by specifying a different port number

```sh
    version: '3'
    services:
      booking:
        image: "local/booking:1.0"
        ports:
          - "7081:80"
      engine:
        image: "local/engine:1.0"
        ports:
          - "7082:80"
```

I tried to run the containers in AKS using a different port but fail. The only reference I'm able to find to host multiple containers using [Basic Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic) or [HTTP(s) Application Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing).

Is it possible to run multiple containers (that use port:80) in a single AKS and publicly accessible using different port numbers?

Comment: http application routing is basically a basic controller + external dns (and also not supported), so if you dont need the external dns part or if you want to go to production with this setup - basic controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it very much is. I suggest you start to read up on Ingress Controllers. There is a basic tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic). This describes exactly your scenario with multiple pods running on port 80 and exposing APIs.

Or, if you are fine running them on different ports, its even easier by using Kubernetes Services ([with Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are able to do it by just configuring an Ingress Controller. As oppose to what @silent said, I would recommend you to consider to use an Azure Application Gateway as Ingress Controller for your AKS cluster. Please have a look at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/application-gateway-ingress-controller-for-azure-kubernetes-service/) that explains you how to quickly and easily configure it. Hope it helps.

Comment: The advantage of Application Gateway over the Azure Load Balancer is that apart both services provide Load Balancing, Application Gateway is a WAF as well, and does the Load Balancing at layer 7 (application layer), instead of Layer 4, and provides you features such as URL-based routing, redirection, Secure Sockets Layer (SSL/TLS) termination and more. So apart from redirecting and load balancing the traffic to your cluster, you can also control the access security to your cluster as well, and more.

Comment: Full list of features here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/features

Comment: I'm not opposed at all to using the AppGW ingress controller ;) It sounded, however, like the OP is still quite a the beginning of his journey, so I'd recommend ngnix as an easier way to start off

Comment: nginx is free, works cross platforms and doesnt require 10 minutes to change a single setting. I'd suggest against using Application Gateway anyday.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I would say Nginx is not free, since how are you planning to host your nginx instance in Azure? At the end, you will end up paying for one or other. And not talking about which one is the most expensive, in my opinion there is a factor that is critical here - time. Application Gateway is PaaS, so it gives you an abstraction of the environment hosting it, so you save a lot of time while managing it, in my humble opinion. But at the end, it is the decision of the author which one to choose, and what are the key factors for him.

Comment: @silent maybe I did not use the best words to explain myself. Sorry about that. I meant with my answer that I would rather choose to use Application Gateway in this scenario, instead of Azure Load Balancer. And yes, Ngnix is another option, but considering that it is not a PaaS in Azure, you would spend time configuring and managing the environment to host your Nginx instance, correct?

Comment: no, not correct, ingress does this for you. and application gateway is just overly complicated, slow, expensive and platform specific

Comment: @4c74356b41 ok. so how do you host the nginx instance in Azure? VM?

Comment: its a basic ingress controller in kubernetes

Comment: so in that case, I would say it is not free, right? Considering that hosting the kubernetes cluster in Azure, using AKS, and the AKS pricing model you pay for the virtual machines instances, storage and networking resources consumed by your Kubernetes cluster. So nginx as pod in the cluster will consume more compute and more networking. am I correct?